# Matching rows in separate datasets based on multi-column indices in R

Tags: r, excel

I have two datasets with the same columns, but different values in the columns. I want to be able to perform an operation similar to ["Index-match"](http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/3/) in Excel such that a row from one dataset matches up to it's equivalent row in the other so that I can perform operations on the lined up data.

For example,

```
#create example dataframes
d1 <- data.frame(country = c('US','US','US','DE','DE'), 
            type = c('A','B','C','A','B'),
            val = c(1,6,3,3,7))

d2 <- data.frame(country = c('US','DE','US','BR','DE'), 
             type = c('B','C','A','B','C'),
             val = c(2,2,33,0,9))
```

I would like to match the rows in `d1` that correspond to `d2` and do `d1$val - d2$val` and save a new dataframe, `d3` that will be only the rows who's key columns matched.

In this example, `d1[1,1:2]` matches `d2[3,1:2]` so they should line up,etc.

Comment: Try `merge(d1, d2, by = c('country', 'type'))[1:2]`

Comment: does merge operate on an inner join?

Comment: By default, it gives the inner join, but you can specify the `all.x`, `all.y` or `all=TRUE` for different options.